# Conflict with template for publication in a journal

Tags: templates, journal

I'm having some problems in submitting a paper to a journal. More precisely, the South American Journal of Logic requires a template in the form

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{sajl}

\volume{X}
\issue{X}
\year{20XX}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\usepackage{latexsym, amssymb, amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[definition]{Remark}
\newtheorem{remarks}[definition]{Remarks}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
\newtheorem{examples}[definition]{Examples}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{Corollary}


\newcommand{\negr}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newenvironment{proof}{\noindent\bf Proof. \rm}{\hfill $\negr{\blacksquare}$       \\}


\title{Template for SAJL}{Template for South American Journal of Logic}

\author{J.-Y. B\'eziau and M. E. Coniglio}{Jean-Yves B\'eziau and Marcelo E.     Coniglio}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

......
```

where sajl.cls is

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2009/09/24]
\ProvidesClass{sajl} [2014/08/12 v1.0 LaTeX document class for South American       Journal of Logic]

% Toma como base la clase "article.cls"
\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,float,multicol}

% Definición de comandos propios de sajl
\newcommand{\volume}[1]{\gdef\@volume{#1}}
\global\let\@volume\@empty
\newcommand{\issue}[1]{\gdef\@issue{#1}}
\global\let\@issue\@empty
\renewcommand{\year}[1]{\gdef\@year{#1}}
\global\let\@year\@empty
\newcommand{\authorname}[1]{\noindent {#1} \newline}
\newcommand{\address}[1]{#1 \newline}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{ \textit{E-mail: }\texttt{#1} \vspace{0.5cm}}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\vspace{0.5cm}\noindent \textbf{Keywords:}\ #1}

% redefinición de la generación del título
\renewcommand*{\title}[2]{\gdef\@shorttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\author}[2]{\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}\gdef\@author{#2}}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \Large\textbf\@title\normalsize\vskip\baselineskip\par
    \@author\vskip\baselineskip\par
 \endgroup
}


% Define el tamaño de página y las márgenes
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3cm, includehead]{geometry} % incluiyendo encabezados en las márgenes
 %\usepackage[letterpaper,top=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry} % incluyen encabezados y pié de página en las márgenes

% define los encabezados de las páginas
\@twosidetrue
\renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfill \textsc{\@shorttitle} \hfill \thepage}%
\renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\thepage \hfill \textsc{\@shortauthor} \hfill}%
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}%     
\renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\@oddfoot}%     

% Incluye la información de la revista al comienzo del artículo
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \label{FirstPage} 
    {
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        {
            \small
            \thispagestyle{empty}
        \noindent {\em South American Journal of Logic} \newline
        \textsf{Vol. \ifx\@volume\@empty??\relax\else\@volume\fi,  n. \ifx\@issue\@empty??\relax\else\@issue\fi, 
    pp. \pageref{FirstPage}--\pageref{LastPage}, \ifx\@year\@empty??\relax\else\@year\fi} \newline
    \textsf{ISSN: 2446-6719} % (Print)  \ \ \textsf{2446-6719} (Online)  
    }
    \begin{flushright} 
        \includegraphics[scale=0.05]{logo-sajl1}
       \end{flushright}
       \end{multicols}
    \vspace{1cm}
  }
}

\endinput
```

However my template is

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4 paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amscd, amsthm, latexsym, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand{\negr}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\renewenvironment{proof}{\noindent\bf Proof. \rm}{\hfill $\negr{\blacksquare}$ \\} 


\newcommand{\nsubset}{\not \subset}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\textnormal{Hom}}
\newcommand{\mono}{\rightarrowtail}
\newcommand{\epi}{\twoheadrightarrow} 
\newcommand{\incl}{\hookrightarrow} %inclusion%
\newcommand{\fib}{\twoheadrightarrow} %fibration%
\newcommand{\cofib}{\rightarrowtail} %cofibration%
\newcommand{\Sub}{\textnormal{Sub}} %subobject%
\newcommand{\Quot}{\textnormal{Quot}} %quotient%
\newcommand{\Sk}{\textnormal{Sk}} %skeleton%
\newcommand{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}
\newcommand{\Ob}{\textnormal{Ob}}
\newcommand{\Type}{\textnormal{Type}}
\newcommand{\Mono}{\textnormal{Mono}}
\newcommand{\OX}{\ensuremath{\mathscr{O}}}
\newcommand{\aff}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{A}^n}}
\newcommand{\Spmax}{\textnormal{Spmax}}
\newcommand{\Spec}{\textnormal{Spec}}
\newcommand{\Open}{\textnormal{Open}}
\newcommand{\Proj}{\textnormal{Proj}}
\newcommand{\Sch}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{Sch}}}
\newcommand{\sob}{\textnormal{sob}}
\newcommand{\Ker}{\textnormal{Ker}}
\newcommand{\Coker}{\textnormal{Coker}} 
\newcommand{\Sym}{\textnormal{Sym}}
\newcommand{\colim}{\textnormal{colim}}
\newcommand{\Supp}{\textnormal{Supp}}
\newcommand{\AffSch}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{AffSch}}}
\newcommand{\QCoh}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{QCoh}}}
\newcommand{\Frac}{\textnormal{Frac}}
\newcommand{\charac}{\textnormal{char}}
\newcommand{\Der}{\textnormal{Der}}
\newcommand{\ad}{\textnormal{ad}}
\newcommand{\Inn}{\textnormal{Inn}} 
\newcommand{\Ho}{\textnormal{H}}
\newcommand{\im}{\textnormal{Im}}
\newcommand{\coim}{\textnormal{Coim}}
\newcommand{\Rng}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{CRing}}}
\newcommand{\sSet}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{sSet}}}
\newcommand{\Sing}{\textnormal{Sing}}
\newcommand{\Top}{\textnormal{Top}}
\newcommand{\Lan}{\textnormal{Lan}}
\newcommand{\Ran}{\textnormal{Ran}}
\newcommand{\PrSh}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{PrSh}}}
\newcommand{\Res}{\textnormal{Res}}
\newcommand{\SC}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{S}}}
\newcommand{\LRS}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{LRS}}}
\newcommand{\RS}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{RS}}}
\newcommand{\Cat}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{Cat}}}
\newcommand{\Sh}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{Sh}}}
\newcommand{\Mod}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{Mod}}}
\newcommand{\Ab}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{Ab}}}
\newcommand{\Grp}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{Grp}}}
\newcommand{\ie}{{\it i.e.}}
\newcommand{\resp}{{\it resp.}}
\newcommand{\Um}{\textnormal{Um}}
\newcommand{\SR}{\textnormal{SR}}
\newcommand{\GL}{\textnormal{GL}}
\newcommand{\F}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{F}}}
\newcommand{\E}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{E}}}
\newcommand{\G}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{G}}}
\newcommand{\Li}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{L}}}
\newcommand{\A}{\textnormal{Aut}}

\begin{document}



\title{blah blah}
\author{blah}
\date{2016}
\maketitle

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\providecommand*{\defiautorefname}{Definition}

\newtheorem{ax}{Axiom}[subsection]
\providecommand*{\axautorefname}{Axiom}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\providecommand*{\thmautorefname}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\providecommand*{\propautorefname}{Proposition}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\providecommand*{\lemautorefname}{Lemma}

\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\providecommand*{\corautorefname}{Corollary}

\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[subsection]
\providecommand*{\conjautorefname}{Conjecture}


\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\providecommand*{\remautorefname}{Remark}

\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[subsection]
\providecommand*{\exautorefname}{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

When I try to simply add

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{sajl}

\volume{X}
\issue{X}
\year{20XX}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

and exclude

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4 paper, twoside]{article}
```

It doesn't compile. It gives me the error `Missing \begin{document}`.

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

I could successfully compile after excluding the packages `hyperref` and `tikz` (and the related packages). Now I would like to know what was causing this conflict in the 'sajl.cls'.

**EDIT**

As noticed by jon, indeed, the package 'geometry' have been excluded in order to successfully compile it. However, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Well, a lot of your 'template' is unneeded for the journal, so you should exclude it. (And if you can't tell what that is, it probably means you don't need it in your own 'template'.) Other things are loaded in both versions, so make sure you only load them once. Start by removing those two types of packages, and then edit your question to give a more stripped down version of the problem.

Comment: @jon I think I found the problem. After excluding the hyperref and tikzcd everything works. Now I would like to know what exactly in the .cls file causes this conflict.

Comment: That seems surprising to me. I would've thought loading `geometry` twice with different options would cause an error....

Comment: @jon Sorry I forgot to mention. Yes, I have omitted 'geometry'. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conflict with the `hyperref` package:** The class `sajl` executes some code `\AtBeginDocument`, like a `\label` command. The hyperref package redefines the `\label` command, but only `\AtBeginDocument`. Since the package is loaded after the class, the first `\label` command is executed before it is redefined, so inconsistent information is written to the aux file.

Bottomline: `sajl.cls` is incompatible with the package `hyperref`.

**Conflict with `tikz`:** The class `sajl` redefines `\year`:

```
\renewcommand{\year}[1]{\gdef\@year{#1}}
```

This is not wise since `\year` is a pre-defined macro containing the current year; `\showthe\year` currently gives `2017` (unless redefined). The code for random number generation in `tikz` relies on the original meaning of `\year`.

Bottomline: `sajl.cls` is incompatible with all packages using `\year`, among them `tikz`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just out of curiosity, when tikz need to generate a random number? More precisely, what command relies on this process? It's kind of impressive at least for me.

Comment: @user40276 The random function belongs to the math library offered by `pgf` and can be used by all packages building on it. It seems that `circuitikz` uses it.